# Calling Tkinter frame controller from function rather then button command

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tkinter

So I have the following, which works perfectly:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LoginPage, ProjPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=12, columnspan=6, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Btn = tk.Button(self, text="Sign In", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ProjPage))
```

But I want that last button command to be in a separate function, so I can do some evaluations first:

```
        Btn = tk.Button(self, text="Sign In", command=self.signIn)

    def signIn(self):
        # do some stuff here
        self.controller.show_frame(ProjPage)
```

This doesn't work; regardless if I try to pass the controller, or use a lambda, nothing seems to work >.<
What am I not getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't seem to initialize `controller` in `self`. Put it there in `__init__` of `LoginPage`, like so:

```
self.controller = controller
```

Comment: Omg so easy! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

my program has a page(main page) that has 5 radio button in it and a button "ok",and I have 5 other Frame. I want my program to go to these frames after clicking the "ok" ( based on the chosen radio button).

when the "ok" is clicked it will call a lambda and get the value of chosen radiobutton and based on this valuefind the string (veg) which represent the name of the page.

here is the code:

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from win32print import StartPage

class KBSapp(tk.Tk):
    def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.**init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default="icon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Diseases and pests of vegetable crops")
        container = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=200, bg='black')
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

```
    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage,carrot,celery, potato, wheat, bean):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise( )
```

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)

```
    label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
    label.pack()

    button2 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : okclick(v) ,text='OK', width=25)
    button2.pack( )

    v = tk.IntVar( )
    self.option1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="Carrot", variable=v, value=1);self.option1.pack( )
    self.option2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="Celery", variable=v, value=2);self.option2.pack( )
    self.option3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="potato", variable=v, value=3);self.option3.pack( )
    self.option4 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="wheat", variable=v, value=4);self.option4.pack( )
    self.option5 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="bean", variable=v, value=5);self.option5.pack( )
    v.set(1)  # initializing the choice
```

def okclick(v):
    global veg
    input1=v.get( )
    if input1==1:
        veg="carrot"
    if input1==2:
        veg='celery'
    if input1==3:
        veg='potato'
    if input1==4:
        veg='wheat'
    if input1==5:
        veg='bean'
    print(veg)

class carrot(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(celery) , text='celery', width=25)
        button3.pack( )

class celery(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(potato) , text='potato', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

class potato(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(wheat) , text='wheat', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

class wheat(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(bean) , text='bean', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

class bean(tk.Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.**init**(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage) , text='StartPage', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

app = KBSapp( )
app.mainloop( )